# Compare two array instances in php

Tags: php, arrays, diff

I have two `array`s in my script.

```
$array1 = array("a" =>'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10');
$array2 = array("b" => '1','3','4','6','7','8','10');
```

I want to compare those array and find items which is exist in `$array1` but not in `$array2`.
For this I use `array_diff($array1, $array2)` which gives o/p like this `Array ( [0] => 2 [3] => 5 [7] => 9 )`.
But I want o/p like this `Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 5 [2] => 9 )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort the array after the difference using [sort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php).

```
$array1 = array("a" =>'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10');
$array2 = array("b" => '1','3','4','6','7','8','10');
$diff = array_diff($array1, $array2);
sort($diff);
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/yREvAg

Or like others are writing, you could use the [array_values()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Answer (score 3):

Try with [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values):

```
$output = array_values(array_diff($array1, $array2));
```

Output:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => string '5' (length=1)
  2 => string '9' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

use [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$array1 = array("a" =>'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10');
$array2 = array("b" => '1','3','4','6','7','8','10');

$diff = array_diff($array1, $array2);
```

For reset keys, use [array_values](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
$reset = array_values($diff);
```

Comment: I corrected my answer, when you edited your question. If you want reset keys, use array values

Answer (score 0):

```
$temp = array_diff($array1, $array2)
$result = array();
foreach($temp as $key => $value){
     $result[] = $value;
}
```